# Symfony 4 - Use environment variable in dev and test

Tags: symfony, variables, testing, environment-variables, getenv

as part of a training on Stripe on Symfony, I am trying to set up an environment variable for testing.

So I have to set a variable to false for testing. And for other environments, the variable must be true.

So, I did this :

```
#.env.test:
VERIFY_STRIPE_EVENT=false
```

and

```
#.env:
VERIFY_STRIPE_EVENT=true
```

Next, I want to test if I have the good value.

So in my controller, I test : `dd(getenv("VERIFY_STRIPE_EVENT"));` with dev environment.
But it returns false.

It means that I can't get the variable.
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: You defined `.env.test` and `.env`. Now you're speaking of "dev" env. If you didn't mistaken, you need a `.env.dev` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to line to .env

```
APP_ENV=prod
```

Add this to line to .env.test

```
APP_ENV=test
```

Add this to line to .env

```
APP_ENV=prod
```

Add this to line to .env.stage

```
APP_ENV=stage
```

Now, your getenv("VERIFY_STRIPE_EVENT") will return the correct variable depending on which environment you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Check your APP_ENV you need to have it ind dev and you also need a .env.dev and clear dev cache at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you did however call config:cache during local development, **you can undo this by deleting the bootstrap/cache/config.php file**. Otherwise, you might experience that calling getenv() will not return the desired values